# The image doesn't show on my web page (I'm using html only for now)

Tags: html

```
<img src="https://pixabay.com/photos/wolf-wolves-forest-wintry-1341881/"
alt="image"
title= pixabay
```

Is this right? My image is not showing up on the web page I'm creating.

Comment: Your tag isn't closed properly and you're missing quotes around the title, but https://pixabay.com/photos/wolf-wolves-forest-wintry-1341881 isn't even an image, it's a page

Comment: Visit the src URL in your browser and you'll see it's the URL of a page about the image, not the jpeg itself. You should download the jpeg, put it on your server, and use your URL in the src attribute. Note that in general you should not embed images from someone else's server: it costs them (a tiny amount for each load, but it adds up over thousands or millions of requests) and it gives them control over what appears on your page.

Comment: Also it sends their server some data about your page's visitor: IP address (hence ISP and approximate location), OS and browser version (User-Agent), the hostname or URL of your page, maybe more.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/20/19/47/wolf-1341881_1280.jpg" alt="image" title="pixabay">
```

Comment: How is this an answer? At best you posted a comment

Comment: To be fair, this is runnable, and it repairs the URL.